# Ethernet not being detected from USB 2.0 adapter

Tags: debian, networking, usb

I am trying to connect to the internet with Debian Sid and kernel 4.16-rc4 on my Wii U. It recognizes the USB 2.0 device when I plug it in, but when I connect the ethernet cable to  the device, it does not detect a network connection. I am using an ASIX AX88772B USB 2.0 device.

```
ip a
```

shows the device as a network connection, but the address never changes when I plug the ethernet cable in. I've tested the ethernet cable and it works fine.

I have the same issue on my Ubuntu Kylin Desktop, but the adapter works fine in Win 7.

In addition, I have no desktop interface at the moment and I have to manually transfer via usb any debs I need to install due to no internet. Just a little bit irritating :D

**EDIT**
here is the output of ip a:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: enx0050b6244c6e: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:b6:24:4c:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.14.124/22 brd 192.168.15.255 scope global enx0050b6244c6e
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:b6ff:fe24:4c6e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is after running `dhclient -v`

Comment: What does `ip addr` actually show? Without the details, it's very difficult to guess at what you're seeing. As well, does `dmesg` show anything?

Comment: I remember vaguely trying a cheap adapter with the same chipset, and it was not particularly well supported.

Comment: If you are stuck on USB ethernet, try a Linksys product. They are well supported by Linux drivers, except probably for LEDs.

Comment: @ErikF I added the output of ip a, there is nothing going on in dmesg. everything is normal there

Comment: do you see an `asix` entry in the output of `lsmod`?  if not, have you trying `modprobe asix` to see if that loads the module and generates the devices?

Answer (score 0):

Try running dhclient manually to request an address:

```
dhclient -v yourinterface
```

If you're not running a DHCP server in your network then you might just add a static address manually:

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.100/24 dev yourinterface
```